# Behavior inconsistency between Rectangle and FancyBboxPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've noticed an inconsistency between how the Rectangle and FancyBBoxPatch objects are drawn. I would expect the following code to produce two nearly identical squares.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, FancyBboxPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)

bbox1 = Rectangle((0.4, 0.4), .1, .1,
                  transform=ax.transData, ec='red',fill=False)

bbox2 = FancyBboxPatch((0.4, 0.4), .1, .1, boxstyle='square',
                       transform=ax.transData, ec='green',fill=False)
ax.add_patch(bbox1)
ax.add_patch(bbox2)

f.show()
```

The actual results are not as expected.  When plotted in an interactive window, panning and zooming works as expected for an object using `transData`. It seems that the initial size and position of the `FancyBBoxPatch` is not being set as I expect.  Can you tell me what I'm missing?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the etiquette is for simple cases of RTFM, but I'll post the answer rather than deleting the question.

The 'square' style has a padding of 0.3 around the box by default.  Setting `pad=0` yields consistent results.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, FancyBboxPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)

bbox1 = Rectangle((0.4, 0.4), .1, .1,
                  transform=ax.transData, ec='red',fill=False)

bbox2 = FancyBboxPatch((0.4, 0.4), .1, .1, boxstyle='square,pad=0',
                       transform=ax.transData, ec='green',fill=False)
ax.add_patch(bbox1)
ax.add_patch(bbox2)

f.show()
```

Comment: Just remember to accept your own answer when the system will let you.